# TypeError from hstack on sparse matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two csr sparse matrices. One contains the transform from a `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer` and the other converted from a numpy array. I am trying to do a `scipy.sparse.hstack` on the two to increase my feature matrix but I always get the error:

```
TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

Below is the code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer="char", lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1, 2), strip_accents="unicode")
ngram_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(df["strings"].values.astype(str))

list_other_features = ["entropy", "string_length"]
other_features = csr_matrix(df[list_other_features].values)

joined_features = scipy.sparse.hstack((ngram_features, other_features))
```

Both feature matrices are `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` objects and I have also tried not converting other_features, leaving it as a `numpy.array`, but it results in the same error.

Python package versions:

```
numpy == 1.13.3
pandas == 0.22.0
scipy == 1.1.0
```

I can not understand why it is talking about `coo_matrix` object in this case, especially when I have both matrices converted to `csr_matrix`. Looking at the scipy code I understand it will not do any conversion if the input matrices are `csr_matrix` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code of [`scipy.sparse.hstack`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L434-L464), it calls [`bmat`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L501-L622), where it **potentially** converts matrices into `coo_matrix` if fast path cases are not established.

---

**Diagnosis**

> Looking at the scipy code I understand it will not do any conversion
>   if the input matrices are `csr_matrix` objects.

In `bat`'s [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L501-L622), There are actually more conditions besides two matrices being `csr_matrix` before it will not be turned into `coo_matrix` objects. Seeing the source code, one of the following 2 conditions need to be met

```
# check for fast path cases
if (N == 1 and format in (None, 'csr') and all(isinstance(b, csr_matrix)
                                               for b in blocks.flat)):
    ...
elif (M == 1 and format in (None, 'csc')
      and all(isinstance(b, csc_matrix) for b in blocks.flat)):
    ...
```

before [**line 573**](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/sparse/construct.py#L573) `A = coo_matrix(blocks[i,j])` to be called.

---

**Suggestion**

To resolve the issue, I would suggest you make one more check to see whether you meet the fast path case for either `csr_matrix` or `csc_matrix` (the two condition listed above). Please see the whole source code for `bat` to gain a better understanding. If you do not meet the conditions, you will be forwarded to transform matrices into `coo_matrix`.

Comment: In the end, it was as you said, the conditions were not met. I had confused N and M so that was the condition it failed on. Now it is running effortlessly.

Comment: @Tobias glad it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear whether this error occurs in the `hstack` or after when you use the result.

If it's in the `hstack` you need to provide a traceback so we can see what's going on.

`hstack`, using `bmat`, normally collects the `coo` attributes of all inputs, and combines them to make a new `coo` matrix.  So regardless of inputs (except the special cases), the result will be `coo`.  But `hstack` also accepts a `fmt` parameter.

Or you can add a `.tocsr()`.  There's no extra cost if the matrix is already `csr`.